# Display Rating Bar based on the number we retrieve from the database

Tags: android, sqlite

**MainActivity.java**

```
int averageRating = db.getUserRating(usersAddr);
Log.d("rating value",""+averageRating); 
TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rating);
view.setText("Rating:"+averageRating);
ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll);
```

**Databasehelper.java**

```
public int getUserRating(String userMac)
{
int avgRating = 0 ;
String selectQuery = "SELECT AVG(rate) as average FROM " + TABLE_RATING + " WHERE "
        + KEY_RECEIVERID + "='" + userMac+"'";

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

if (cursor!= null)
{
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        Log.d("CURSOR POSITION",  ""+cursor.getPosition());
        avgRating = cursor.getInt((cursor.getPosition()));
        Log.d("average", ""+cursor.getInt((cursor.getPosition())));
        System.out.println(cursor.getInt((cursor.getPosition())));
    }
}
return avgRating;
}
```

**XML file**

```
<LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for retrieving the average rating from the database.I am displaying it as a text.But i want to display the rating in the form of rating bar.Can you help me?

Comment: where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a rating bar like this:

```
  <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then change your activity accordingly:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    RatingBar ratingBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ratingBar=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    ratingBar.setRating(4);   //put your value here like ratingBar.setRating(averageRating); 

    // Set ChangeListener to Rating Bar
    ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
        boolean fromUser) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your Selected Ratings  : " +   String.valueOf(rating),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        });

}
}
```